# Populating a listview with images from the SD card (not a set amount of items in list)

Tags: android, image, listview

Basically I'm trying to make a contact list like the one provided by Android. When populating the listview with items, using a SimpleCursorAdapter you can easily get all the names to appear in the R.id.textview of each item:

```
private void fillData() {
        mCursor = mDbAdapter.fetchAllContacts();
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);
        String[] from = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.contact_name};
        SimpleCursorAdapter contacts = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_view, mCursor, from, to);
        this.setListAdapter(contacts);
    }
```

Something like that. I've searched and found sample code for both getting images  from online, or displaying a set number of images in the items (for instance you know you have 5 items so you get the 5 matching images). But I really don't know where I'd begin on getting images from my SD card, and displaying them in the proper item. The images are named according to the id of the contact, so I do have the means to call the proper image.

A push in the right direction would be much appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: @Jeff Gilfelt gave a great answer, but I went ahead and spoke too soon when saying I could figure out the rest on my own... haha. I have a default image declared in the xml for the contacts like Android does. When I implement the new Adapter, it like compresses the items into nothing, I figure because it finds an empty bitmap @ that location. So I did the following:

```
@Override
public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String id) {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File path = new File(root, "path/images/thumbs/"+id+".jpg");

    if(path.exists()) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapStatic.getThumb(id);
        v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else {
        super.setViewImage(v, id);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't help either. Any ideas?

EDIT2: Figured out the above problem. Simply go like this:

```
    else {
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.default);
        v.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
```

Hope this helps others! Remember for this solution you will have to add a Context member var, and the line `mContext = context` in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subclass of SimpleCursorAdaptor and override the setViewImage method such that it constructs the path to the appropriate file on the SD card from the id you feed it, then use BitmapFactory.decodeFile to create a Bitmap you use for the image view you are binding to:

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String id) {

        String path = "/path/to/sd/card/" + id + ".png";
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        v.setImageBitmap(b);

    }

}
```

Then add your contact id from the cursor and the view id of your ImageView to the to/from arrays that you pass to the adapter. Example:

```
private void fillData() {
    mCursor = mDbAdapter.fetchAllContacts();
    startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    String[] from = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME, DBAdapter.ID};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.contact_name, R.id.contact_image};
    MySimpleCursorAdapter contacts = 
        new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_view, mCursor, from, to);
    this.setListAdapter(contacts);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much, this works perfectly. I will need to add some lines to have the image default to to the image I set the ImageView to in the xml if the contact does not have a profile picture (right now the entire item is compressed into a tiny sliver if the contact does not have an image), but I can definitely figure that out myself. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Spoke too soon, if you see this check out my question, I added a followup to it. My attempts to fix the adapter to still show the default image has failed, any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. In your else case, if you call `v.setImageResource` with your default placeholder resource id, does that solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

and this post http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/64048.aspx

Have a two dimensional arraylist, the first element containing the contact name and the second containing the image.After you read the images into a bitmap, save the bitmap in your contacts arraylist. Have a custom arrayAdapter which contains a textView and a imageView as its row elements, set the contact name and image in the getView() of the array adapter. Refer this post for custom listViews http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/

This should help you get going.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) chapter on the Android development guide. By calling getExternalFilesDir() you will get a filepath to your SD card.

As a strategy, if you navigate to the folder containing the images and just pass in the ID of your contact to locate the file, you can load this into a data structure.

You can then create a custom adapter passing in the data structure containing your images. This will result in your ListView to contain only the images of your contacts.

This is just to give you a head start!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a subclass of `SimpleCursorAdapter`, just create a `ViewBinder` which handles the set up of the your image for each row.

`ViewBinder.setViewValue` will be called for all `View`s in your row (as specified in your layout xml) so make sure you return false for any view which is not an instance of ImageView.

```
ViewBinder viewBinder = new ViewBinder(){

    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

        if (view instanceof ImageView){

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;

            String imageFilename = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            imageView.setImageURI(imageFilename);

            return true;
        } 

        return false;
    }

};
cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(viewBinder);
```